# Accessing macOS Calendar events to calculate hours worked

Tags: macos, api, calendar

I’d like to add up how much time I spend working each week.

I keep track of when I work by entering an event in a dedicated calendar that I subscribe to in macOS/iOS Calendar.

My first ideas were:

- Is there a way to do this with Shortcut (the new Automator?)
- Is there an AppleScript approach to take?
- Maybe I can form or access an API that serializes the calendar event objects to a format I can consume in another programming environment like Ruby or Smalltalk?
- Should I skip trying to use macOS calendar and see if I can authenticate to the calendar feed and work directly from there with a calendar library?

Thanks in advance for an ideas you might have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out using Shortcuts, the new version of Automator!

Here’s what the program looks like:

[image: A macOS Shortcuts program calculating hours worked in a calendar]

Comment: You can simplify this a bit by replacing "repeat" with "Calculate Statistic" with "sum" option https://superuser.com/a/1826581/34572

Comment: @WojtekKruszewski that’s very kind of you! Thanks

Comment: Could you share the shortcut file?